# How to create a separate measure group for the distinct count

Tags: ssas-2012, measures

I am adding distinct order count measure to the cube.
I have to place it in a separate measure group for better performance
When I click on "new measure group" button, I am presented with a dialog box "select a table from the source view" . My Facts_sales table is not on the list. because the table is already used by other measure group "Facts_sales".

How could I create a new measure group for the distinct count measure?

Answer (score 4):

Just create a new measure in the group referencing the fact table of interest.  As long as you select Distinct Count as the aggregation function, the new measure will auto-magically be placed in its own separate measure group.

EDIT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166573.aspx

> 13.In the Measures pane, right-click the Sales Quotas measure group, and then click New Measure. For more information, see Defining
>   Measures.
>
> The New Measure dialog box opens, containing the available source
>   columns for a measure with a usage type of Sum.
>
> 14.In the New Measure dialog box, select Distinct count in the Usage list, verify that SalesQuotas is selected in the Source table list,
>   select EmployeeKey in the Source column list, and then click OK.
>
> **> Notice that the measure is created in a new measure group named Sales
>   Quotas 1. Distinct count measures in SQL Server are created in their
>   own measure groups to maximize processing performance.**

Comment: Magic doesn't happen. It creates distinct meausere in the group, referencing the fact table of interest. With a warning "Break distinct count in a separate measure group".

Comment: @user2374904 Page 196 of the Wrox professional SSAS 2012 book shows your situation. I haven't got an instance available to play with at the moment but are you sure you didn't add the measure with a default aggregation originally then change it to distinct count in the properties window after the measure was added?